Modbus FC21 in pympdbus
I run openHAB with the Modbus binding, I’m able to read some addresses from my solar inverter (SolarEdge) where the documentation describes exactly which addresses to use for the different objects.
The next step is to also control some settings on the inverter, most important one is the “Active Power Control”, this number value 0-100 is a percentage type and if you set it to 10 for example, and the max capacity is 2200watt, you throttle it to not return more then 220watt, if 0, it is shut down completely.
And that’s what I want because some times the return kWh turns negative and I’ll have to pay for it. openHAB knows when it turns negative by reading a API, now I only need to find a way to control the inverted over Modbus TCP.
SolarEdge also has documentation about controlling the inverter, but in this case, they don’t use the regular address register number, but they use hexadecimal in the manual.
So for example, I like to control address 0xF001. From what I have read, I need to convert this hex to decimal, then 0xF001 = 61441.
From this point it turns a bit tricky for me, but from what I’ve read, 6 would be the regular write register and 1441 + 1 = 1442 would be the address (correct me if I’m wrong). For this register I should use FC21 but openHAB doesn’t support this (at the moment) so I would like to do this with a python script.
I read that there is support for FC21 on PyModbus but I don’t quite understand how to use it.
The 0xF001 address would be R/W with type uint16.
Now, I saw the minimal example for modbusTCP:
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
    
client = ModbusTcpClient('MyDevice.lan')   # Create client object
client.connect()                           # connect to device, reconnect automatically
client.write_coil(1, True, slave=1)        # set information in device
result = client.read_coils(2, 3, slave=1)  # get information from device
print(result.bits[0])                      # use information
client.close() 

Please guide me in the right direction how to adjust this so I can read and write to this 0xF001 address.

Hexadecimal is really just another way of communicating the same info (as you say 0xF001 is  61441 in decimal; don't read anything further into this). Can you please let us know where you saw the reference to FC21 in the manuals? (as far as I can see this is just a standard holding register). I'd be trying a standard FC06 (Write Single Register) command. Note that I'd suggest testing with mbpoll/modpoll to confirm the device is acting as you expect before trying python (but openHAB should be sufficient).

Thanks for the reply and confirmation that the 61441 value is correct. As of the FC21 part, I didn't read this in the SolarEdge manuals but on other website by a google search: Modbus 60001 FC.
But I really get confused because if you lookup Modbus ranges on google, you get schemas like this: https://assets-global.website-files.com/63dea6cb95e58cb38bb98cbd/6415d9f5d03969605d78143c_62456bb2f92b580ad16d83d3_AN%2520INTRODUCTION%2520TO%2520THE%2520MODBUS%2520PROTOCOL.png
So if I want to read/write to 61441 using FC03 (holding, OH only provides FC1,2,3,4), what would be the start address?

For a holding register you read with FC03 and write with FC06 (or FC16). Unfortunately things get confusing because this is a very old standard and there have been variations over the years - see "When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1 " in this article. Openhab uses the "data frame entity addresses" so I would guess you need to use 61441 for the power limit (the technical note is not as clear on this as the manual is).
